# На localhost работает, а при публикации Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights

Tags: c#, asp.net

При публикации ASP.NET MVC 5 приложения пишет 
`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights`

`The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.`

Подробнее об ошибке можно глянуть на самом сейчас не работающем сайте https://livingearth.space/

Пробовал пересобирать проект, удалять ссылки и заново ставить, удалять и обновлять через nuget Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, не помогает. Сума уже схожу, на компьютере работает, при публикации на хост нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение оказалось простым, я публиковал через FTP, при том не ставил галочку в VS "удалять все перед публикацией". В общем поставил, все заработало. 
А так для тех у кого будет такая проблема и публикуете не через FTP, то просто надо в ручную удалить с хоста все что относится к вашему сайту и загрузить все по новой.